# Windows can not find... Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, drivers, 16-bit, alien

I have bought Alienware 17 laptop. Win 7 didn't have the network driver so I [went to download them from Dell](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/alienware-17/drivers). I then downloaded the driver and copied it to Alien over the USB. But when I run it (by clicking right mouse button and `Run as Administrator`) I am getting weird message.

```
Windows can not find C:\Network_Driver... Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.
```

[image]
Which makes zero sense as I am running it not from command prompt but via windows shell.

**UPDATE:**
Tried running from command line
got error that file in not x64 compatible, says its 16-bit application. Same file on other machine runs just fine.

[image]

**Has anyone encountered something similar before? Why am I getting this message? Can it indicate hardware problem?**

Comment: Verify that the path you typed exists of course. Sounds like it doesn't

Comment: @EricF thats the thing I am clicking right mouse button and running `Run as Administrator` so I can't see how the file can be not there.

Comment: Are you administrator?

Comment: @EricF yes, otherwise I would not get the option. and if gives me same message if I run it with double click too.

Comment: Maybe a loose connection to the HDD?

Comment: Did you try just copying the file to the desktop & running from there. I've seen Windows oddness fixed by that [though usually on network shares]

Comment: @EricF I can copy the file around, which makes even less sense, don't think its HDD connection, as I would get `Blue screen of death` if HDD would disconnect I think.

Comment: @Tetsujin tried Desktop, same error.

Comment: Maybe the file is corrupt? Could try redownloading it

Comment: That path thinks it's right on the C: drive, at root - tried putting it there?

Comment: @Tetsujin yes I am running it from `C:` you can see the file size from behind error message, and other data about file is on the window (screenshot)

Comment: ah, ignore - that's where it appears to be in your pic. Does it return the same path error wherever you put it?

Comment: @Tetsujin yep anywhere I put, I have been working with PC's for  15+ years haven't seen anything like it.

Comment: nope, sorry, I'm stumped too.

Comment: Is the file marked as unsafe? Right click, properties, There should be a button to "unblock", or something. Otherwise you can run a command line (cmd.exe) as administrator and launch it from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

16-bit applications can only run on a 32-bit verisons of Windows. Because you're attempting to run it on a 64-bit version it's not being allowed to run.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/896458

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to scan your pc using software like Malware Bytes, HijackThis and Combofix (and with your antivirus too). You can try to rename your file to something other too, like "a.exe" (maybe there's a name-related issue)

Comment: Windows are brand new, laptop has never seen internet (LAN driver is the one I am trying to install). I would find it hard to believe that windows 7 installation disk that comes from dell would have viruses in it.

Comment: Ok, and this problem shows up with every user on your laptop? Otherwise you'd create another user and migrate your content